# App se rompe al querer agregar un UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy haciendo haciendo una app con Swift 5, la cual cuenta con un viewController(1º) inicial que posee un botón que muestra otro viewController(2º).
El código del 2º viewController es el siguiente:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit
import Firebase
import Hero

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class RegistroViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate {

    //MARK: ATRIBUTOS
    var db: Firestore!

    // Instancias recursos
    let gradientBackground = GradientView()
    let vista = RegistroView()

    //MARK: viewDidLoad()
    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Mostrar fondo gradiente
        gradientBackground.mostrarGradientBackground(viewController: self)

        // Instanciar Firestore
        db = Firestore.firestore()

        // Configuracion navigationBar
        navBarSettings()

        // Mostrar objetos de la vista
        vista.mostrarVista(viewController: self)
    }

    // Funcion para configuracion de navigationBar
    func navBarSettings() {

        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationItem.title = "Registro"
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancelar", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelarRegistro))

    }

    @objc public func cancelarRegistro(sender: UIBarButtonItem!) {
        self.hero.modalAnimationType = .cover(direction: .down)
        self.hero.dismissViewController()
    }

}
```

El código de RegistroView es el siguiente:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class RegistroView: UIView {

    // Color
    let customAzul = UIColor(red: 137/255, green: 177/255, blue: 223/255, alpha: 1)

    //scrollView y stackView
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let stackView = UIStackView()

    // Objetos para stackView
    let datosPersonales = UILabel()
    let nombreTextField = UITextField()
    let apellidoTextField = UITextField()

    func mostrarVista(viewController: UIViewController){

        // Instanciar viewController recibido
        let vc = viewController

        // Agrego scrollView a la vista del viewController
        vc.view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // Configuracion scrollView
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: vc.view.frame.width, height: vc.view.frame.height * 2)
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }

        // Agrego stackView al scrollView
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        // Configuracion stackView
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stackView.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.width.equalToSuperview() // Ancho igual al scrollView
            maker.top.equalToSuperview().inset(10) // Posicion Y de arriba: 10px más abajo
            maker.bottom.equalToSuperview() // Posicion Y de abajo: igual a scrollView
            maker.centerX.equalToSuperview() // stackView centrado horizontalmente
        }

        // Fuente para labels
        let fuente = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .bold)

        // leftView para textFields
        let leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 10.0, height: 2.0))

        // Configuracion datosPersonales
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(datosPersonales)

        datosPersonales.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        datosPersonales.text = "Datos Personales"
        datosPersonales.textColor = UIColor(red: 66/255, green: 135/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1)
        datosPersonales.font = fuente

        // Configuracion nombreTextField
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(nombreTextField)

        nombreTextField.text = ""
        nombreTextField.placeholder = "Nombre"
        nombreTextField.autocapitalizationType = .words
        nombreTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        nombreTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        nombreTextField.layer.borderWidth = 4
        nombreTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 66/255, green: 135/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        nombreTextField.leftView = leftView
        nombreTextField.leftViewMode = .always
        nombreTextField.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.8)
            maker.height.equalTo(45)
        }

        // Configuracion apellidoTextField
        /*stackView.addArrangedSubview(apellidoTextField)

        apellidoTextField.text = ""
        apellidoTextField.placeholder = "Apellido"
        apellidoTextField.autocapitalizationType = .words
        apellidoTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        apellidoTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        apellidoTextField.layer.borderWidth = 4
        apellidoTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 66/255, green: 135/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        apellidoTextField.leftView = leftView
        apellidoTextField.leftViewMode = .always
        apellidoTextField.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.8)
            maker.height.equalTo(45)
        }*/
    }

}
```

El 2º viewController tiene un scrollView, el cual contiene un stackView. Cuando el stackView contiene el primer label (datosPersonales) y el primer textField (nombreTextField), funciona bien; pero al momento de agregar el segundo textField (apellidoTextField) al stackView y correr la app de vuelta, al momento de tocar el botón en el 1º viewController que me dirige al 2º, la app se congela, no puedo hacer más nada y Xcode no me muestra ningún error ni se finaliza la ejecución de la app.

Cómo puedo resolver esto?

**NO** estoy usando Storyboards

Comment: Si agregas un punto de interrupción en viewDidLoad() del View Controller que recibe la llamada?

Answer (score 0):

A ver, veo varios problemas de concepto que en el futuro te van a dar problemas, pero no deberían impedir que el código se ejecute.

Lo que creo que sucede es que estás colocando una vista, `leftView`, en dos lugares distintos de la jerarquía. NO HAGAS ESO. Simplemente haz una copia de leftView para el segundo (y sucesivos) textField

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: me dices a mi, o al autor original? Funciona este Stack diferente que el StackOverflow en inglés?

Comment: @Diego Atencia probaste mi solución?